# como hago para dividir una cadena de texto en n cantidad de caracteres en python

Tags: python, string, bucle-for, while

necesito dividir en secciones de n caracteres lo que escriba mi usuario por ejemplo el usuario introduce 100 caracteres dividirlo en 10 y mostrar cada subdivicion pero aun no sé como trabajar con los strings.

```
texto = str(input("ingrese el texto "))
longitud_texto= len(texto)
while longitud_texto >0:
   frac=print(texto[0:])
   texto = texto.replace([0:180],'')
```

Comment: Cuál es el error con el código?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Con las cadenas puedes hacer casi cualquier cosa, puedes usar *slices* `[inicio:fin:paso]`, puedes acceder a sus elementos mediante corchetes `str[0]`, etc. Solo no te compliques la vida.

Para hacer lo que quieres vamos a utilizar un ciclo `for` y la notación de *slices*. Los *slices* nos permite *cortar* o *rebanar* y esto nos ayudan a obtener un pedazo de una cadena, o una lista. Si tenemos la cadena `Hola` y hacemos esto `"Hola"[0:3]` esto nos traerá las letras que estan desde la posición hasta la 2 (no se incluye el 3) y tendremos como resultado `Hol` (`H`->posición 0, `o` ->pos 1, `l`->pos 2). Bien esto nos servirá para obtener solo 10 letras de alguna cadena larga, por ejemplo.

```py
cadena = "esto es una cadena"
cadena[0:10] #[inicio:fin]
```

esto nos dará como resultado: `esto es un`. Si queremos seguir agarrando las otras letras pues solo tendremos que sumar 10 al `inicio` y `fin` y esto lo hacemos con un ciclo `for`.

Con el ciclo `for` podemos usar la función `range()` la cual permite 3 parámetros `start`, `stop` y `step`, el parámetro `step` indica en cuanto se incrementará la variable de control así que la usaremos para indicarle que lo haga de 10 en 10.

```py
texto = "esto es un texto muy largo aunque no lo parezca Xd, bueno ahora si se vuelve largo, espera!, aun falta un poco más, bueno vamos a poner japones watashi wa christian naokiri desu, etoo.." 

sep = [] #aqui se guardará cada pedazo

#indicamos que se repita segun el tamaño de la cadena y que vaya de 10 en 10
for i in range(0,len(texto), 10):
    sep.append(texto[i:i+10])  #cogemos desde i hasta i+10 y agregamos
```

Esto mismo se puede lograr con una comprensión de lista.

```py
sep = [texto[i:i+10] for i in range(0,len(texto), 10)]
print(sep)
```

En ambos casos el resultado es:

```
['esto es un', ' texto muy', ' largo aun', 'que no lo ', 'parezca Xd', ', bueno ah', 'ora si se ', 'vuelve lar', 'go, espera', '!, aun fal', 'ta un poco', ' más, buen', 'o vamos a ', 'poner japo', 'nes watash', 'i wa chris', 'tian naoki', 'ri desu, e', 'too..']
```

Comment: +10 por la descripcion detallada de la respuesta, y el texto de ejemplo xD

Comment: Creo que lo correcto seria decir +1 pues estas dando un voto a favor. Y muchas gracias :D

Comment: muchas gracias, me quedó mucho mas claro el ciclo for y como funcionan los strings, pues tenía ciertos vacíos en como usarlo. pude acomodar mi código de la forma que quería con tu explicación

Comment: de nada, recuerda aceptar la respuesta si te fue de ayuda :D